# Create file in JUnit test case in Android

Tags: java, android, junit, android-testing

I am developing my test project to unit test my Android project.

In my test case, I would like to create a file in my computer e.g. under `/Users/MyUserName/Documents/` & write some test result into this file. Is it possible?? How to do it??

```
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        File myTestResult = CREATE_FILE_IN_MY_COMPUTER();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Not like that at least. All test code runs within the phone/emulator and as such has no *direct* access to your computer's file system.

You'd probably have to write a webservice that runs in your machine to which your tests send data via HTTP or similar.

More importantly, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I just want to record the testing results in a file in my computer & make a comparation with other datasources. That's the file could be used by other datasources

Comment: I guess I don't know what you mean by "testing results". Presumably it's not the test results (pass/fail/etc). But yeah, anything other than pass/fail results will have to be something custom.